# Firebase deploy with gulp

Tags: firebase, gulp

I want deploy to firebase just with gulp task. But it doesn't work, nothing happens. Also, I tried to run other commands like `calc` and the result was the same. What I'm doing wrong?

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    exec = require('gulp-exec');

gulp.task('task', function () {
  exec('firebase deploy');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Install `gulp-shell` with `npm install gulp-shell`

---

Add requirement to `gulpfile.js`

```
const shell = require('gulp-shell')
```

---

Setup `Gulp` command...

```
gulp.task('firebase', shell.task([
    'firebase deploy'
]))
```

---

Run it!

```
$ gulp firebase
```